# Pass cookie created by API back to API from Angular app

Tags: angularjs, session, cookies, browser

I have an API that creates a session cookie named 'web_api'. I would then like to access that cookie in my Angular app so that I can pass it back to the API for authorisation purposes. However, using `$cookies.web_api` and `$cookieStore.get('web_api')` yields `undefined`.

Is it possible to somehow pass this cookie back to my API from the Angular app?

My service code is as follows:

```
app.service('apiService', function($http, $q, $cookies, $cookieStore) {
    var host = 'https://127.0.0.1:12344/v1/'

    function test_cookie() {
        console.log($cookies.web_api);
        console.log($cookieStore.get('web_api'));
    }
});
```

Comment: For security purposes, the scope of a cookie is the domain that sets it.

Comment: @popovitsj so there is no way for me to pass the cookie back to the API?

Comment: You can if your web app runs on the same domain as your api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the the API endpoint to `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' = true` and when I made the request I set `withCredentials: true` on the request, e.g.

```
function getUserId() {
    var idPath = 'userId'

    var request = $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: buildUrl(idPath),
        withCredentials: true
    });

    return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
}
```

This resolved the issue.

This answer was based on on the documentation provided here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/